# change CCMenuItem image?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have some complicated menu, which is built differently every time according to a state.

i have this code :

```
CCMenuItemSprite  *sign =  [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",[memoryInstnace getCellImageNumber:i]]] selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",[memoryInstnace getCellImageNumber:i]]]];
CCMenuItemSprite  *playing =  [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playing.png"]
                                                              selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playing.png"]];
            item2=[CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self selector:@selector(play:)items:sign,playing,nil];
            item2.position=pixels[i];
            item2.tag=i;


            Menu= [CCMenu menuWithItems: item2, nil];
```

this is a toggle button so when its on A and hitten it comes to B , but i want that some delegate in the app (NOT when someone hit it ) will change the IMAGE of it from B to become A .

i couldnt do `setNormalImage` to item2.

how can i do that ?
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the [selectedIndex](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_menu_item_toggle.html#adca18155325c3693317fa1b472dc6078) of the CCMenuItemToggle item should do the trick. This will toggle the selected state by negating the current selectedIndex (ie 0 becomes YES and therefore 1 and 1 becomes NO and therefore 0):

```
item.selectedIndex = !item.selectedIndex;
```